# combine number (numpad) and key function

Tags: vb.net-2010

I created a project on vb.net. Now I want to open it with the function keys of the form I want. For example, open a form1 with number 75 Open a form2 with number 25 open a form3 with combine keys 5a

Comment: I want to dial each number in the main form to open the form I want

Comment: Hi, I wrote a project. When I press the keys in the main form, I want the form I want to open, for example, I press the 25 key to open form one.

Comment: If e.KeyCode = Keys.NumPad2 & e.KeyCode = Keys.NumPad5 Then
            Form2.Show()
        End If

Answer (score -1):

I wrote a project. When I press the keys in the main form, I want the form I want to open, for example, I press the 25 key to open form one.